# Minecraft 1.7 Closing on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: launcher, minecraft

I somehow got a 64bit version of ubuntu somehow and my minecraft won't work anymore. The launcher closes then the game window shows up but it's more a screenshot of my desktop then goes back to launcher. I've tried everything to get Minecraft again but I don't know how to update the native folder in bin since they don't have that anymore. Reinstalling and trying different versions of Java doesn't work either.
Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I remember having trouble with MineCraft and having to install 'liblwjgl-java' from Synaptic package Manager (or you can use Software Centre) to get the game working properly, or you can type the following in a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install liblwjgl-java
```

Failing that pop onto minetest.net and get the free MineTest 0.4.9 game which is very lightweight and runs native on any platform...